# How can I add a chatter for many2many fields (tags) in Odoo 16?

Tags: odoo, odoo-13, odoo-14, odoo-15, odoo-16

I want to add chatter for Tags. But odoo does not support tracking of many2many fields.
What should i do?

Any Suggestions.

I tried to put tracking=true on tag_ids field but it does not work.

I am stuck here. Please give your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the [_track_mail](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/project/models/project.py#L1940) function to track `x2many` fields.

Check the code just after `# Many2many tracking` comment in the project module

***Example:***

```py
if len(changes) > len(tracking_value_ids):
    for changed_field in changes:
        if tracked_fields[changed_field]['type'] in ['one2many', 'many2many']:
            field = self.env['ir.model.fields']._get(self._name, changed_field)
            vals = {
                'field': field.id,
                'field_desc': field.field_description,
                'field_type': field.ttype,
                'tracking_sequence': field.tracking,
                'old_value_char': ', '.join(initial_values[changed_field].mapped('name')),
                'new_value_char': ', '.join(self[changed_field].mapped('name')),
            }
            tracking_value_ids.append(Command.create(vals))
```

Comment: I have solved it by myself but your answer seems helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution but i recommend to use Kenly's answer. also posting my solution here if someone needs it.
I did it for tags tracking.

```
    def write(self,vals):
        old_ids = self.tag_ids.ids
        res = super(ModelName, self).write(vals)
        new_ids = self.tag_ids.ids
        if new_ids != old_ids:
            new_tags = str(self.env['tag.tag'].browse(new_ids).mapped('name')).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("'","")
            old_tags = str(self.env['tag.tag'].browse(old_ids).mapped('name')).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("'","")
            message = "<![CDATA[<div class='d-flex align-items-center flex-wrap mb-1'><span class='me-1 px-1 text-muted fw-bold'>" + old_tags + "</span><i class='fa fa-long-arrow-right mx-1 text-600' title='Changed' role='img' aria-label='Changed'></i><span class='me-1 fw-bold text-info'>" + new_tags + "</span><span class='ms-1 fst-italic text-muted'>(Tags)</span></div>"
            self.message_post(body=message)
        return res
```